# Can anyone help me identify this stem binder nut

Tags: parts, stem

This nut (pictured) fits the binder bolt from a vintage 3ttt stem. I would like to know the name of this nut, or the type of nut this is so that I can try to buy more.

[image: stem binder bolt nut bottom]
[image: stem binder bolt nut top]

So far, I've found similar things when searching the internet with keywords like "knurled", "conical", and "tapered", but haven't managed to find anything that has the flange.

Can anyone help?

Edit: For clarification, here's a pic of the nut in situ

[image: 3ttt stem]

Comment: I've never seen anything like it on a bike.  Where exactly is it positioned?

Comment: I'd say a proprietary nut used by TTT. Most stems of that type used standard six-sided (lock) nuts in a six-sided recess. You could be lucky on a vintage parts market.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's wrong with the nut?  (Or do you need a matching one for a different bike?)

Comment: It's the kind of thing that when it's gone amiss makes you throw away an otherwise perfect item.

Comment: A skilled lathe operator could mill one from either an oversized nut or a piece of steel stock.  However it would not be cheap.  Contact a local engineering firm - you'll need measurements and dimensions and thread specs, and possibly some hardness details.

Comment: The diameter of the nut is 1-2mm larger than it needs to be and I was hoping to find a slightly smaller one. The one I have will do the job of holding the handlebars, but the flange doesn't sit flush when the bolt is under the required tension. A bit nitpicky perhaps, but thought I'd put the question out there. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @PaulRoper so its probably the wrong one in the first place - and a previous owner has made do with the best thing they could find.

Comment: Did you ever find these? I have the same stem and looking for a replacement too (I snapped the bolt and managed to find a replacement at a local bike coop).

Comment: @PaulRoper How did you get on in the end?  What did you do to solve or work-around the problem?

Comment: @Criggie As I tightened the stem clamp bolt, the stem clamp binder nut completely dug into the stem, bedding itself in there nicely. It felt odd to do, because it is a slightly destructive process. I never would have expected the stem to deform enough to accommodate the size of binder nut I had — but...it did. After all that though, the stem was too short for me lol

Answer (score 3):

It's called a stem clamp binder nut. The names don't get more specific than that, unfortunately. You could search for the bolt by the stem name, and maybe get lucky finding another one. It's not a super-common setup for stems; they typically used a hex nut.

If it doesn't fit a little further into the stem, it's most likely an incorrect size for the stem. The flange should sit flush when the bolt is fully tightened. The binder bolt thread only comes in a few sizes, so you may just have a bolt that "works" but is not original to the stem.

Answer (score 2):

I've found something similar (only the other way round) for Cinelli:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/Cinelli-1A-stem-clamp-serrated-section-fixing-bolt-and-nut/142719429884 and I was searching for "stem clamp serrated nut". This one has the flange.

Comment: Good match... in case your ebay url is not working use https://www.cinelli-milano.com/products/1a-spare-bolt

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like a "Countersunk External Serrated Tooth Lock Washers"
[Countersunk External Serrated Tooth Lock Washers](https://www.boltandnut.com.au/m6-1-4-stainless-a2-70-g304-countersunk-external-serrated-tooth-lock-washers-din-6798-type-v)
in combination with a lock nut turned upside-down "Hex All Metal Lock Nuts"
[Hex All Metal Lock Nuts](https://www.boltandnut.com.au/m6-x-1-00p-metric-coarse-stainless-a2-70-g304-hex-flange-nyloc-nuts)

Answer (score 1):

As JonR said back in 2018 it is called a stem clamp binder nut. That would be the generic name for any nut used in this context - a handlebar stem.

It can also be called a [knurled spline nut](https://www.cfi1.com/knurled-spline-nut-steel-zinc-plated-c-1_1261_1899.html#1) or just a spline nut.
[image]
The length and diameter are variable parameters.

Don't confuse these with rivet nuts.
Article on [rivet nuts and how they are installed](https://www.sherex.com/blog/why-rivet-nuts/).

If it were me, I'd just find a longer bolt and use a regular nut on the back.